# Excel - insert multiple rows between other rows using pre-defined data

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a way (macro or formula) to insert multiple rows of pre-defined data from sheet2 (4 additional rows) between each existing row on sheet1.

**The predefine data on sheet2 is as following:**

[image]

**The Existing data on sheet1:**

[image]

**The resulting data after - Added rows show in yellow:**
[image]

1. Between Each row of data on sheet1, it needs to add each row from
   Sheet2.
2. Copy Existing data from the ROW and duplicate on new ROW
3. BUT change  the Sublevel column to N on each added Row.

Answer (score -1):

duplicate your data 4 times

```
4332
4333
4335
```

then fill in the data you want (on the duplicated records only)

```
20
21
10
6
```

then change the sublevel to N (on the duplicated records only)

then apply autofilter sort by Projects (A-Z), then sort SubLevel (Z-A)

Comment: Thanks, but will take too long if there are thousands of rows.

Comment: if you have too much formula in sheet, turn off the auto calculation first.

Comment: It will take a couple of days and I need something that I can ideally repeat. Macro or formula.